# doesn't java follow implicit type conversion?

Tags: java

I was solving the following problem on Hacker rank. The program is supposed to print "Weird" onto the screen when N is odd. I checked the condition for N to be odd with the bitwise and(&) operator. But, I was getting this message from the compiler. I recently switched to java from c++. This operation works in C++. I wonder why it's not supported by java.
[image]

```
public class Solution {
private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = scanner.nextInt();
    if(N&1){
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
    else if(N>=2&&N<=5)
    {
       System.out.println("Not Weird"); 
    }
    else if(N>=6&&N<=20){
        System.out.println("Weird");
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Not Weird");
    }

    scanner.close();
}
```

}

Comment: *FYI:* Adding spaces makes the code more readable, e.g. `else if (N >= 2 && N <= 5)`

Comment: @Andreas whatareyoutalkingaboutwhatswrongwithit

Comment: @Michael At least CamelCase your [ScriptioContinua](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scriptio_continua); QUIDQUIDLATINEDICTUMSITALTUMSONATUR.

Answer (score 5):

Java is not C, you can't coerce an `int` to a `boolean`. This

```
if(N&1){
```

should be

```
if ((N & 1) == 1) {
```

Comment: Personally, I would bold, highlight, super-size, etc. the first 4 words, and make it blink in a whole rainbow of neon colors. But that's just me being old and cranky.

Comment: @Andreas Something like J͠a͠v͠a͠ ͠i͠s͠ ͠n͠o͠t͠ ͠C͠ .